# how to select maximum colum in an oracle database using ireport

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports

i want to select max value for a column. i tried using the `max(inodometer)` but it's giving me an

> error: not a single-group group function

Here is exactly what i am doing:

```
Select tm.actualstartdate, tm.actualduration, tm.returndate, tm.documentno, tm.dateofrequest, **max(tm.inodometer)**

(select registration from tm_vehicle where tm_vehicle_id=tm.tm_vehicle_id) as regnumber,

from tm_trips tm where tm.TM_Trips_ID=$P{RECORD_ID}
```

Comment: You need to use the group by on all non-aggregate columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAX() in ORACLE SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404982/max-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select tm.actualstartdate, tm.actualduration, tm.returndate, tm.documentno, tm.dateofrequest, **max(tm.inodometer)**,
(select registration from tm_vehicle where tm_vehicle_id=tm.tm_vehicle_id) as regnumber from tm_trips tm where tm.TM_Trips_ID=$P{RECORD_ID}
**GROUP BY tm.actualstartdate, tm.actualduration, tm.returndate, tm.documentno, tm.dateofrequest, select registration from tm_vehicle where tm_vehicle_id=tm.tm_vehicle_id)**
```

When doing aggregation functions (like MAX, MIN, SUM) on columns, you have to put ALL other columns in the group by.

Comment: Any other way to get a maximum column value being filtered by another column because my query is too long to repeat the entire query after the group by clause

Comment: Try an inline query in your selection. Something like: select val1, (select max(val2) from x where y=z) maxval from tab. Check if performance is acceptable with your dataset.