# MAX() in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, max

I have a table that stores a list of records for Maintenance tasks that have been done and the date and time that they were done. I'm trying to do a sub-query to pull out the records for each task that has the most recent date. My SQL statement is:

```
    SELECT "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."EO" AS "EO",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."AC" AS "AC",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."PN" AS "PN",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."PN_SN" AS "PN_SN",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."HOURS_RESET" AS "HOURS_RESET",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."MINUTES_RESET" AS "MINUTES_RESET",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."CYCLES_RESET" AS "CYCLES_RESET",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_DATE" AS "RESET_DATE",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_HOUR" AS "RESET_HOUR",
       "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_MINUTE" AS "RESET_MINUTE",
       MAX ( "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_DATE" ) AS "LAST_COMP_DATE"
  FROM ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE
GROUP BY ( "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."EO" ) ,
       ( "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."AC" ) ,
       ( "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."PN" ) ,
       ( "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."PN_SN" )
```

However I keep getting the following error: "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

When I remove the "GROUP BY" then I get:
"ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"

1 - what exactly does that mean
2 - what is wrong with the statement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+not+a+single-group+group+function

Comment: 4 upvotes for a question that can easily be answered by a little googling? SO really does have an interesting dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520608/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression)

Comment: The question may have been a duplicate but the explanations weren't stated to where I could apply them to my issue. Sorry and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns which ever you added in the SELECT clause without an aggregate function should be in the GROUP BY clause.

To make it little bit clear:
Take this Example:

You have TransactionID, AccountID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate in your SELECT Clause, and you need SUM(TransactionAmount) on all dates, in that case, if you add

```
SELECT TransactionDate, TransactionID, AccountID, SUM(TransactionAmount) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY TransactionDate
```

Then you will get an error, why because
Assume you have a 4 transactions on 20160101 and each transactionAmount is $1000 
Your result expectation will be

```
TransDate      TransAmt
 20140101          4000
```

In this case, if you bring other attributes in the SELECT clause like AccountID and TransactionID, where will they go? This is why we have to include all the attributes in GROUP Clause what ever in the SELECT clause except the one which is with the AGGREGATE function.

Comment: Thank you - I don't get the error anymore - however I am also NOT getting just the most recent date either. Is it because of the other information I'm requesting to be listed or am I missing something? I took out the "Reset_Date" since that is what is in the MAX clause but now I'm stuck again. Thank you for your help in this

Comment: Are you stuck still?

Comment: Yes I am. I only need the most current date for each item but I'm getting all of the dates. :(

Comment: Can you remove the reset date, reset hour and reset minute from your select and group by. Why are you using reset date and max(reset date)???

Answer (score 2):

You should set all the column in group by

```
 SELECT "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."EO" AS "EO",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."AC" AS "AC",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."PN" AS "PN",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."PN_SN" AS "PN_SN",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."HOURS_RESET" AS "HOURS_RESET",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."MINUTES_RESET" AS "MINUTES_RESET",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."CYCLES_RESET" AS "CYCLES_RESET",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_DATE" AS "RESET_DATE",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_HOUR" AS "RESET_HOUR",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_MINUTE" AS "RESET_MINUTE",
   MAX ( "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_DATE" ) AS "LAST_COMP_DATE"
FROM ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE
GROUP BY  "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."EO"  ,
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."AC"  ,
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."PN"  ,
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."PN_SN" , 
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."HOURS_RESET" ,
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."MINUTES_RESET" ,
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."CYCLES_RESET" ,
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_DATE",
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_HOUR" ,
   "ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE"."RESET_MINUTE"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know MySQL at all, however, in Oracle, you need to group by *all* non-aggregate funtion columns listed in the select list.

Something like this should work:

```
 SELECT "engineering_compliance"."eo"               AS "EO", 
       "engineering_compliance"."ac"               AS "AC", 
       "engineering_compliance"."pn"               AS "PN", 
       "engineering_compliance"."pn_sn"            AS "PN_SN", 
       "engineering_compliance"."hours_reset"      AS "HOURS_RESET", 
       "engineering_compliance"."minutes_reset"    AS "MINUTES_RESET", 
       "engineering_compliance"."cycles_reset"     AS "CYCLES_RESET", 
       "engineering_compliance"."reset_date"       AS "RESET_DATE", 
       "engineering_compliance"."reset_hour"       AS "RESET_HOUR", 
       "engineering_compliance"."reset_minute"     AS "RESET_MINUTE", 
       Max ("engineering_compliance"."reset_date") AS "LAST_COMP_DATE" 
FROM   engineering_compliance 
GROUP  BY "engineering_compliance"."eo", 
          "engineering_compliance"."ac", 
          "engineering_compliance"."pn", 
          "engineering_compliance"."pn_sn", 
          "engineering_compliance"."hours_reset", 
          "engineering_compliance"."minutes_reset", 
          "engineering_compliance"."cycles_reset", 
          "engineering_compliance"."reset_date", 
          "engineering_compliance"."reset_hour", 
          "engineering_compliance"."reset_minute";
```

Answer (score 2):

You must put all columns of the SELECT in the GROUP BY